# Error al compilar proyecto de NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, spring, boot

He creado un proyecto en NetBeans y no compila, obtengo el siguiente error:

> *Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project trabajofinal: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]*
>
> *To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.*

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sin el log completo y mas informacion, no sabemos que pasa igual que vos...

Comment: Hola Isabel, ve a: **run/set project configuration/customize** en la nueva ventana vas a: **run** y en el campo **Arguments** escribes **-e switch -X switch**,  luego vuelves a compilar y nos comentas que errores te arroja.

Comment: hola Cris gracias por la respuesta realice todo lo que indicas y me sigue saliendo el mismo error